# PySpark AnalysisException : Cannot resolve column name

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to resolve the following error, I have already seen a couple of post on this but am unable to resolve.
**org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "features" among *all the columns**

Things I have tried:

```
tempList = [] 
for col in Df.columns:
    new_name = col.strip()
    new_name = "".join(new_name.split())
    new_name = new_name.replace('.','')
    tempList.append(new_name) 
Df = Df.toDF(*tempList)
```

I just have 6 columns in my Spark dataframe and all of them **ONLY** have charaters and underscore.
Scheme for the dataframe:

```
StructType(List(StructField(A,ShortType,true),StructField(B,ShortType,true),StructField(C,IntegerType,true),StructField(D,IntegerType,true),StructField(E,StringType,true),StructField(F,DoubleType,true),StructField(G,IntegerType,true)))
```

I am trying to implement PCA from here, https://www.nodalpoint.com/pca-in-spark-1-5/

Code for reference:

```
df = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]).toDF(("a_1", "b", "c"))

def estimateCovariance(df):
    m = df.select(df['features']).map(lambda x: x[0]).mean()
    dfZeroMean = df.select(df['features']).map(lambda x: x[0]).map(lambda x: x-m)  # subtract the mean

    return dfZeroMean.map(lambda x: np.outer(x,x)).sum()/df.count()

def pca(df, k=2):
  cov = estimateCovariance(df)
  col = cov.shape[1]
  eigVals, eigVecs = eigh(cov)
  inds = np.argsort(eigVals)
  eigVecs = eigVecs.T[inds[-1:-(col+1):-1]]  
  components = eigVecs[0:k]
  eigVals = eigVals[inds[-1:-(col+1):-1]]  # sort eigenvalues
  score = df.select(df['features']).map(lambda x: x[0]).map(lambda x: np.dot(x, components.T) )
  scoreDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(score.map(lambda x: (DenseVector(x),)), ['pca_features'])
  # Return the `k` principal components, `k` scores, and all eigenvalues

  return components.T, scoreDF, eigVals

comp, score, eigVals = pca(df)
score.collect()
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @oldwooki Created a dataframe to replicate the same error(see edit). Hope this is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the article you have linked to:

> The input to our `pca` procedure consists of a Spark dataframe, which includes a column named `features` containing the features as `DenseVectors`.

A bit further, you are given an example of how to construct a sample dataset:

```
>>> data = [(Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0]),),
...     (Vectors.dense([2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]),),
...     (Vectors.dense([4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0]),)]
>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data,["features"])
```

Your dataset contains the data in a number of distinct columns. You need to trun this into a single column of vectors. Spark ML has a tool for that, namely `pyspark.ml.feature.`[`VectorAssembler`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler).

In your case, you need something like:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["a_1", "b", "c"], outputCol="features")
comp, score, eigVals = pca(vectorAssembler.transform(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have a column `features` - if I'm understanding the problem correctly, all columns are features in this example, so you would want to select all columns.